# Set LinearLayout into TableRow programmatically

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, tablerow

I have the next layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/foto"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"/>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/nombre"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/posicion"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And I would like to set this layout to a TableRow programmatically.
Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: You were right. I've used LayoutInflater and it worked. I post the solution below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Cristian suggested, using LayoutInflater solved my problem.
This is the code for my activity:

```
public class SeleccionarJugador extends Activity {

private TableLayout mTablaJugadores;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    // Se establece el layout
    setContentView(R.layout.jugadores);

    // Se recupera la tabla donde se insertán los jugadores de ambos equipos
    mTablaJugadores = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabla_jugadores);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    TableRow fila = new TableRow(this);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fila_seleccionar_jugadores,null);
    TextView dorsal = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dorsal);
    dorsal.setText(String.valueOf(11));
    TextView nombre = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nombre);
    nombre.setText("Pepe");
    TextView posicion = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.posicion);
    posicion.setText("Lateral");
    fila.addView(v);
    mTablaJugadores.addView(fila);

}
```

I "inflate" one View with the layout which I would like to insert into each row, and I take the components inside the Layout, manipulate them, and then insert the View into the row.
Finally, just I have to insert the row into the Table and That's it!.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: But it didn't keep fila_seleccionar_jugadores style! I used weight = 1 for each TextView, and fill whole layout_width, but with your code, They are clining to each other!